# Apache .htaccess error: 'not allowed here' on Debian Wheezy

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am trying to configure an apache virtualhost which needs to be password protected in the root directory.

So I created a .htpasswd file (with sha passwords) and configured the .htaccess file. Howevery whatever I do, on the webpage I get an error 500 (internal server error) and in the error.log I see this:

```
/var/www/ninja/www/.htaccess: deny not allowed here
```

or if I leave the deny out of the .htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile not allowed here
```

Both .htpasswd and .htaccess file are readable for apache and are set to the www-data user and group. I also tried adding these rules to the virtualhost config file but that didn't do the trick either.

Can you please help me out?

Thanks!

config file apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ninja

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ninja/www
    ServerAlias ninja

    <Directory /var/www/ninja/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

htaccess file: (placed in /var/www/ninja/www/)

```
Deny from all
#Allow from (You may set IP here / to access without password)
AuthUserFile /var/www/ninja/.htpasswd   
AuthName authorization
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Here is an ls of the mods-enabled directory

```
alias.conf -> ../mods-available/alias.conf
alias.load -> ../mods-available/alias.load
auth_basic.load -> ../mods-available/auth_basic.load
authn_file.load -> ../mods-available/authn_file.load
authz_default.load -> ../mods-available/authz_default.load
authz_groupfile.load -> ../mods-available/authz_groupfile.load
authz_host.load -> ../mods-available/authz_host.load
authz_user.load -> ../mods-available/authz_user.load
autoindex.conf -> ../mods-available/autoindex.conf
autoindex.load -> ../mods-available/autoindex.load
cgi.load -> ../mods-available/cgi.load
deflate.conf -> ../mods-available/deflate.conf
deflate.load -> ../mods-available/deflate.load
dir.conf -> ../mods-available/dir.conf
dir.load -> ../mods-available/dir.load
env.load -> ../mods-available/env.load
mime.conf -> ../mods-available/mime.conf
mime.load -> ../mods-available/mime.load
negotiation.conf -> ../mods-available/negotiation.conf
negotiation.load -> ../mods-available/negotiation.load
php5.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.conf
php5.load -> ../mods-available/php5.load
reqtimeout.conf -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.conf
reqtimeout.load -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.load
setenvif.conf -> ../mods-available/setenvif.conf
setenvif.load -> ../mods-available/setenvif.load
status.conf -> ../mods-available/status.conf
status.load -> ../mods-available/status.load
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Apache Directory directive on /var/www/ninja/www/ only allows modification of the behaviour of `FileInfo Indexes` by way of the .htaccess file. Refer to the Apache documentation on [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Please modify the `AllowOverride` to also allow the local configuration of `AuthConfig` resulting in:

```
<Directory /var/www/ninja/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes Authconfig
</Directory>
```

Comment: thanks, the error 500 is gone, 'I do get You don't have permission to access / on this server.' I take it that would be the htaccess generating that?

Comment: O and can anybody explain why the -1 ?

Comment: Also keep in mind to add the AuthConfig configuration to both SSL and non-SSL apache config files in case you have them seperated.

Answer (score 6):

Your configuration should add **AuthConfig Limit** at

> AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes

Becomes

> AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes **AuthConfig Limit**

Comment: Only `Limit` needed.